Integrating Core ML model into an Xcode App
I'm integrating a CoreML image recognition model in Xcode, and whenever I run it, it always says that it can't find the bundle at the path. However, if instead of creating the model myself, I download one from the internet, even though that error appears, it correctly performs the predictions.
I've tried creating another model, checking if the versions are compatible, and verifying if the model is well integrated, but nothing works.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is more reliable to use the model’s initializer.
let model = try YOLOv3Tiny(configuration: .init()).model

Replace YOLOv3Tiny with your model’s name.
